# Mini overview map in a UWP App using MapControl

Tags: c#, dictionary, uwp, mercator

I'm trying to build a mini overview/orientation map that is synchronized with a full MapControl view, like this: ([Full Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg3Jp.png))

[image: this picture]

I'm getting trouble trying to calculate the width, height and location of the little red rectangle that is inside the mini map according to the MapControl's size, location and zoom.

It should be synchronized with the MapControl's view, and a click on the small map should also change the CenterPoint of the MapControl.

The full map is a MapControl in UWP and a the mini-map is just a Border UIElement over a static image.

I'm using the following formulas. They works but not accurately. The error margin is pretty noticeable, specially for big zooms.

For calculating the location and the size of the red rectangle:

```
var positions = MapControl.GetVisibleRegion(MapVisibleRegionKind.Near).Positions.ToArray();
var topLeft = positions[0];
var bottomLeft = positions[1];
var topRigt = positions[2];

//Transfering the Longitude system from [-180, 180] to [0, 360]
var centerX = (MapControl.Center.Position.Longitude + 180) * (SmallMapWidth / 360);

//Transfering the Latitude system from [-90, 90] to [0, 180]
var centerY = (-MapControl.Center.Position.Latitude + 90) * (SmallMapHeight / 180);

var topLeftX = topLeft.Longitude + 180;
var topRightX = topRigt.Longitude + 180;

//MapControl wraparound by default. In that case, the topRightX might be smaller than topLeftX, as it will start from the 'beginning'.   
var deltaX = Math.Abs(topLeftX - (topLeftX < topRightX ? topRightX : 360 - topRightX));

//The width of the red rectangle
SmallMapViewPortWidth = Math.Abs(deltaX) * (SmallMapWidth / 360);

//The height of the red rectangle
SmallMapViewPortHeight = Math.Abs(topLeft.Latitude - bottomLeft.Latitude) * (SmallMapHeight / 180);

//The center point of the red rectangle.
RedRectangleCenterPoint = (centerX - SmallMapViewPortWidth / 2, centerY - SmallMapViewPortHeight / 2);
```

The following is for navigating the MapControl to a point that was clicked on the overview map. *X* and *Y* are the point that was clicked relatively to the overview map.

```
var lon = 360 * x / SmallMapWidth - 180;
var lat = 90 - 180 * y / SmallMapHeight;
```

What is wrong with my calculations? Why there is a pretty noticeable error margin?

Comment: Please post your code and let's know what you have done.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I've updated my question with the formulas that I'm using. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Um, that's not the formula that the MapControl uses. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx). You're using an equirectangular projection, but the MapControl uses Web Mercator (spherical).

Comment: @RaymondChen The documentation reference a 'levelOfDetails' value while MapControl  exposes only ZoomLevel. Is there a way for obtaining the levelOfDetails? The results are inaccurate when using ZoomLevel as levelOfDetauls.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The zoom level / level of detail is irrelevant. You are going to rescale the results to match your mini-map anyway, so the scale is not important.

Comment: @RaymondChen the results are still inaccurate. I'm doing the following:
1. Get the Size using TileSystem.MapSize(1). 2. get the ratios: ratioX = size / SmallMapWidth and ratioY = size / SmallMapHeight. 3. X = point.x * ratioX and y = point.y * ratioY. 4. Calculate the lat and lon by calling TileSystem.PixelXYToLatLong(x, y, 1, out var lat, out var lon).
It seems that the X-coordinates are accurate, but the there is a big margin in the Y-coordinates.

Comment: I misread. You are using the latitude/longitude reported by the MapControl, which means that the transformation has already been reversed. You need to convert the latitude/longitude into the projection of your mini-map. I would debug this by taking -25.58524° N, 134.5041° E and seeing whether that results in a red rectangle around Australia. If not, then the problem is in your conversion from latitude/longitude to mini-map coordinates. I can't tell what projection your mini-map uses, so I can't help with the math there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually the image that I was using for the orientation map. It was resolved once I started using proper Bing Maps images.

It seems there is an official API for rendering images in different sizes based on Bing Maps' projection
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map